# how To Create a ltr/rtl Class With Jquery Attribute

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to create a ltr/rtl class with Attribute. My actual problem is, example i have 2 section card with button. if i click on button. all of section change all together
but i want to change clicked section not all of them

I want to have rtl and ltr on the page

Is it possible to write the code more optimally?

**This is my code:**

EXAPMLE : https://codepen.io/meysamrad/pen/YzBjaxv

**html**

```
<main>
  <section class="card">
    <div>
      <button class="btn btn__rtl">RTL</button>
    </div>
    <div class="code__example">
      <h3 class="text">Button Close</h3>
    </div>
  </section>
   <section class="card">
    <div>
      <button class="btn btn__rtl">RTL</button>
    </div>
    <div class="code__example">
      <h3 class="text">Button Close</h3>
    </div>
  </section>
</main>
```

**sass**

```
main {
  max-width: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.card {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    margin: 40px 0;
}
.btn {
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    gap: 5px;
    padding: 0.8em 1.2em;
    line-height: 1;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out 0.0s;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.text {
  text-align: left;
}

[dir="rtl"] .text {
  text-align: right;
}

.code__example {
  &.rtl-active {
    direction: rtl!important;
  }
}
```

**jquery**

```
let code__example = document.querySelector(".code__example");

$(".btn__rtl").on("click", function () {
  
    $(".code__example").toggleClass("rtl-active")
  
    let direction = code__example.getAttribute('dir')
    
    if (direction === 'rtl') {
        $(".code__example").attr('dir', 'ltr');
        $(".btn__rtl").html("rtl");
    } else {
       $(".code__example").attr('dir', 'rtl');
       $(".btn__rtl").html("ltr");
    }
  
});
```

Please tell me the best solution for jQuery or Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

You can access the properties on `this` (the currently clicked button) instead of selecting every element with a certain class.

```js
$(".btn__rtl").on("click", function(e) {
    const $this = $(this);
    const $code_example = $this.closest('.card').find('.code__example').toggleClass('rtl-active');
    const direction = $code_example.prop('dir');
    if (direction === 'rtl') {
        $code_example.prop('dir', 'ltr');
        $this.html("rtl");
    } else {
       $code_example.prop('dir', 'rtl');
       $this.html("ltr");
    }
});
```

```css
.card,main{width:100%}article,aside,details,figcaption,figure,footer,header,hgroup,main,menu,nav,section{display:block}ol,ul{list-style:none}blockquote,q{quotes:none}blockquote:after,blockquote:before,q:after,q:before{content:"";content:none}table{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0}*{box-sizing:border-box;-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;text-decoration:none;border:none;outline:0}main{max-width:400px;margin:0 auto}.card{position:relative;display:flex;flex-direction:column;padding:20px;border-radius:10px;background-color:#f9f9f9;margin:40px 0}.btn{display:inline-flex;align-items:center;justify-content:center;gap:5px;padding:.8em 1.2em;line-height:1;border-radius:4px;background-color:#000;color:#fff;text-transform:uppercase;cursor:pointer;transition:.3s ease-out;overflow:hidden}.text{text-align:left}[dir=rtl] .text{text-align:right}.code__example.rtl-active{direction:rtl!important}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<main>
  <section class="card">
    <div class="">
      <button class="btn btn__rtl">RTL</button>
    </div>
    <div class="code__example">
      <h3 class="text">Button Close</h3>
    </div>
  </section>
   <section class="card">
    <div class="">
      <button class="btn btn__rtl">RTL</button>
    </div>
    <div class="code__example">
      <h3 class="text">Button Close</h3>
    </div>
  </section>
</main>
```

Comment: @radman Happy to help.